# finite dimensional function space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I'm studying Arzela-Ascoli (particularly as a generalization of Bolzano-Weierstrass) and am wondering how to think of functions as generalizations of points in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Specifically, I'm looking for intuition motivated by basic linear algebra ideas (bases, relations between different dimensions of the space). So if I'm building toward understanding infinite dimensional function spaces, can you first describe how we move from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to finite dimensional function spaces as an intermediate step (particularly emphasizing the role of equicontinuity)?

Comment: A vector $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$ is like a function that takes an integer $i$ as input (where $1\leq i \leq n$) and returns the number $x_i$ as output. A function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is like a vector that has one component for each real number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One transitional example is to look at the vector space of real-valued functions on a set with $k$ elements, such as $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$, with addition pointwise ($(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$) and scalar multiplication similarly. This is a $k$-dimensional space of functions. Indeed, hard to tell it apart from $\mathbb R^k$. Equicontinuity is relatively easy...

Comment: Thanks -- so what would the "basis" of this space be?

Comment: @jjjjjj, one basis would be the functions $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_k$ where $f_i(j)=0$ for $j\not=i$, and $f_i(i)=1$. (Like a Kronecker delta.) Of course, there are many different bases for vector spaces.

Comment: Ok, so if we describe the basis of a set with a finite number $k$ of functions, what's the analog in an infinite dimensional space? Can you give a simple example of how we'd write the basis?

Comment: Again, there's no "the" basis, but only "a" basis... For example, the polynomial functions on $\mathbb R$ (with real coefficients) have a basis $1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots$, because every polynomial is a (finite) linear combination of these. This vector space also has a basis $1, x-1, x^2-x, x^3-x^2, \ldots$.

Comment: Oh ok, so each of $1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots$ represent a "vector" over $\mathbb{R}$, or rather, a "point" in this vector space of polynomial functions?